# Difference between CommandLine.arguments and Processinfo.processinfo.arguments in swift

Tags: swift, command-line-arguments

I wanna know how these are different
[CommandLine](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/commandline)
[ProcessInfo](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/processinfo)

```
let elements = CommandLine.arguments
let elements = Processinfo.processinfo.arguments
```

In my thinking, ProcessInfo’s arguments have all of the Commandline's concept. So there is no differences for dealing with argument.

The code below, using CommandLine.arguments, is for practicing read and write file.

If I put Processinfo.processinfo.arguments at location of CommanLine.arguments. Nothing changed.

```
static func makeInOutFile() -> (inputFile: String, outputFile: String)? {
    let elements = CommandLine.arguments
    let inputFile: String
    let outputFile: String
    switch elements.count {
    case 2:
        inputFile = elements[1]
        outputFile = Message.ofDefaultJSONFileName.description
        return (inputFile: inputFile, outputFile: outputFile)
    case 3:
        inputFile = elements[1]
        outputFile = elements[2]
        return (inputFile: inputFile, outputFile: outputFile)
    default:
        print (Message.ofFailedProcessingFile)
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: If you’re looking at alternatives for parsing command line arguments in Swift, consider Apple’s [Argument Parser](https://apple.github.io/swift-argument-parser/documentation/argumentparser/). It gets you out of the weeds of manual argument parsing and is available via SPM.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`CommandLine` is part of the Swift standard library and only provides the command line arguments and the argument count.

`ProcessInfo` is part of the Foundation framework (not part of the language). While `ProcessInfo.arguments` does gives you the same results as `CommandLine.arguments`, there is a lot more to the `ProcessInfo` class.

While the two `arguments` are functionally the same, if all you want is the command line arguments, use `CommandLine`. It's simpler, it doesn't rely on any additional frameworks, and it would be more portable to other Swift runtimes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!!